# When does borrow end?

Tags: rust

Why is this not allowed in the first case, and allowed in the second case?  When does the borrow end?

```rust
use regex::Regex;
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let REGEX_TEST = Regex::new(r"\hello\").unwrap();
    let mut msg = Cow::from("Hello, world!");

    msg = REGEX_TEST.replace(&msg, "bye");   

    println!("{}", msg);
}

fn main2() {
    let mut msg ="Hello, world!".to_string();

    msg = msg.replace(&msg, "bye world");  

    println!("{}", msg);
}
```

Error is:

```bash
  |
8 |     msg = REGEX_TEST.replace(&msg, "bye");
  |     ^^^                      ---- borrow of `msg` occurs here
  |     |
  |     assignment to borrowed `msg` occurs here
  |     borrow later used here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, `&msg` is only borrowed for the duration of the `replace` call, after which a `String` is returned and assigned to `msg`. Since `&msg` isn't needed anymore once that `String` is created, it's fine.

In the first case, `Regex::replace` actually returns a `Cow<'t, str>` where `'t` is the lifetime of the `&msg`. (It does this so that if no replacements are made, it can return a borrowed form of the original string instead of reallocating.) So the return value of `Regex::replace` needs the original `msg` to keep existing so that this reference remains valid. Overwriting `msg` with the return value of `Regex::replace` would destroy the data that the reference points to, which Rust rightly doesn't allow.

Comment: The question is, when does borrow end.  You are saying that lifetime 't needs to be (at least as long as &msg, which it is)
Are you saying, borrow doesn't end until msg is released?  That's obviously not true since it is used after in#2.  The error is specifically 

(See error above)

How can returning a cow be useful, if you have to hold it elsewhere?  What if you want to regex 100s of cases?

Comment: Or, if in order to do this, you need to make a copy, then it kind of defeats the purpose of using a cow?

Comment: @playerone usually you wouldn't use a `Cow` as _input_ to `replace`. E.g. `let msg = "Hello, world!"; let msg = REGEX_TEST.replace(&msg, "bye");` [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=964ca9f393e058d663a3799b92a8e32d).

Comment: @Jmb Well, imagine I use cow_replace().  But anyways, how then, do you avoid an unnessesary allocation?

Comment: I guess I'll take this answer, but I'm not satisfied